# How to change background color on click?

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to change the background color on click. It does not seem hard but the problem is I have button in another Kivy file, not in main. How to get property from this `button` and change its color?

Here's my try(code):

```
Python:

easy_button = ObjectProperty()
def easy_button(self):
        self.GAME_SPEED = 0.5
MainKV:
#:import menu menu

Game:

<Game>:
    menu_canvas: menu_canvas
    score_widget: score_widget
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'images/pixel.jpg'
    Label:
        font_name: "fonts/PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf"
        text: "SCORE " + str(root.score)
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos_hint: {"x": .03, "y": .8}
        font_size: self.width/3.5
        opacity: 0
        id: score_widget
    MenuWidget:
        id: menu_canvas
 
Second Kivy File:
<MenuWidget>:
    Button:
            text: "Easy"
            font_name: "fonts/PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf"
            size_hint: .18, .15
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: .5, 1, .5, .85
            on_press: root.parent.easy_button()
            pos_hint: {"x": .2, "y": .1}
            font_size: self.width/5.5
            id: easy_button
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change background colour in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099231/how-to-change-background-colour-in-kivy)

Answer (score 0):

Good day. Any kv imported allows you to use the imported widgets as you wish. When you call the widget, give it an [id](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets) and you could alter its properties directly or in callback.

In your case, you would need to add a property to the `MenuWidget` of the id of the child button. Then you could change the properties of the child button by changing the properties of the button using the id in callback function.